# Stop and resume scroll page on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a query with simple demo, I want to stop scroll on `button1` click and on `button2` then scroll will be resume. I don't know how I do this?

Fiddle [`here`](http://jsfiddle.net/xcUCT/)

HTML:

```
<input type='button' value='stop scroll' id='btn1'>
    <input type='button' value='resume scroll' id='btn2'>
        <div> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, ... <div>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "stop scroll" ? try to explain please

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "stop scroll" and "resume scroll"?

Comment: Stop scroll me page cannot scroll on mouse wheel down

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var allowScroll = true;

    $("div").on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e){ 
       if (!allowScroll){
          e.preventDefault();
       }
    });

    $('#btn1').click(function(){
       allowScroll = false;
    });

    $('#btn2').click(function(){
       allowScroll = true;
    });

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xcUCT/1/)

Comment: As long as you realise that this *only* stops scroll action, not other methods of page navigation e.g. arrow keys, page up, etc...

Comment: @gvee: The OP states this: `Stop scroll me page cannot scroll on mouse wheel down` in his comment.

Comment: Hi Khanh, I saw his comment. I just want to ensure that the OP (and future readers) appreciate that stopping mouse scroll does not mean stopping navigation :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you are able to add a handler to the "mousewheel" event (use [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) for browser support) and do something like:

```
$('#my_elem').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
    event.preventDefault(); //to prevent the default action
    // or $("html, body").scrollTo(0);
});
```